# Can I Get the background doc of an open uidoc in another window?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I was trying to avoid save conflict in my application when I discovered something stange... Question: could I use this or this is ack, evil code? Is it "well known" or is it true only in my configuration Notes 8.5.3?

I have an ui-**opened** saved notes document: *main*.

A lotusscript code updates this doc in background. Let's do this from **another** form. What should happend ? *Main* should be updated in background, and if we try to save it lately (manually) from the opened *main* document, we should get a save conflict, right? Well not if the following code exists in the *postopen* for *main*'s form.

*Main* will be reset to the disk version **upon modification** by the code of the other document. I mean the opened document will be reloaded to the background doc. And all unsave changes will be lost, without any warning. I said it's strange!

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidocument)
    Dim UIDoc As NotesUIDocument
    Set UIDoc = source 
    Dim tmpDoc As NotesDocument
    Set tmpDoc=UIdoc.Document
End Sub
```

Bellow is an example of code that makes the update. I simply put this code in an action of another form. I hard coded the UNID of the *main* document for simplicity of code. Update this UNID to the *main* UNID.

Even IsUIDocOpen returns true! Could I assume that the background doc of the *main* opened document is returned by the db.GetDocumentByUNID in the **second** form ? And if yes why does it work **only** if the code in postopen is present ?

```
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim ldoc As NotesDocument ' ,doc As NotesDocument

Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
Set ldoc = _
db.GetDocumentByUNID("028935D543C50A2AC2257E06004EFB7F") ' doc.LinkedDocID(0))

If ldoc.IsUIDocOpen Then
    If Messagebox ( "changing background doc will reset uidoc to disk version !",1, _
    "linked doc is open !") <> 1 Then Exit Sub
End If
ldoc.fakefield = "inserted changed on " + Cstr(Now)
```

Comment: After opening a PMR, IBM pointed 2 technotes:Changes made by front-end methods are lost after update to the back-end document (1084505)
http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21084505 and When do changes made to the current document, using back-end classes, refresh on screen? (1098273) http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21098273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I Get the background doc of an open uidoc in another window?

Yes.  But let's clarify: when you open a document in the UI (like by double clicking or hitting Enter in a view), if it is *already* open in another window or frame, notes will try to change the focus to that window or frame (it doesn't always succeed with frames, but I digress).  Opening via script is different unless you call NotesUIWorkspace.editDocument, in which case you're emulating the UI document open event.

But a "backend" document is just the document on disk, as you already know, and the UI is just the form displaying the data loaded up with it.  You can surface one document with multiple forms using form formulas, but the above behavior still applies - if the document is open elsewhere, you have the potential for a save conflict.

So long as you manage things properly to prevent two simultaneous actions saving to a document, you should not have a save conflict.  You can do this in a number of ways, like enabling conflict management, enabling document locking, or providing some other mechanism such as a messaging queue.

> Even IsUIDocOpen returns true! Could I assume that the background doc of the main opened document is returned by the db.GetDocumentByUNID in the second form ?

Yes, this will always be true.  The UI doesn't care, all the NotesDatabase method GetDocumentByUNID knows to do is consult the main index and return the document object to you for that data note.

> And if yes why does it work only if the code in postopen is present ?

Clarifying "only" here, you must have some handle to the backend object, which is what your code provides.  There are other ways to accomplish the same task, such as placing similar code in another form event or action button / hotspot click event.

The thing to remember is that when you ask the NotesDatabase for a document, you get a pointer to to *that* document.  You *can have multiple pointers* to the same document and that is generally where you start to get into trouble with save conflicts if you are not managing the save events properly.

Comment: Interesting, I will read this again. Your remark, "You can have multiple pointers to the same document" describe perfectly the situation. It would be great to have the possibility to access to the pointer without READING the doc from disk. It could allow 2 screens to interract with the SAME doc without reverting(resetting) the first pointer to the disk version (thus loosing all unsave change).

Comment: Note that LotusScript is implicitly ByReference.  If you wanted a copy of a document handle, you could make a function that returns it ByValue I suppose, or make a copy in memory to a secondary handle.  But the value of this, IMO, outweighs the cost of managing the solution this way.  It's a good indicator that the data structure needs to be a bit more normalized (not something Notes encourages by design) if you find use cases where you need to simultaneously update or use the same document from two different contexts at the same time.

Comment: I open a PMR concerning the loose of unsaved data. I will update later this question.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm starting to check if I can find an elegant solution to deal with multiple pointers to the same document without causing save conflict and modification lost (this last point is even more difficult). I guess I will have to deal with virtual/version document to avoid direct writing to the doc and agent recopying changes to the main document, I've done such things long time ago and it was not simple at all..

Comment: Glad to provide some input.  A mechanism I have used in the past for this sort of complexity is to implement a messaging queue using a separate view and document as messages, and an agent to process these, one at a time, to provide a mutex for writes to documents.  This puts the write authority in the hands of a single agent, but introduces a delay in executing your document writes.  You would instead put your values to be written into separate "message" documents and let the agent apply them in the order received and then move them out of the messaging queue.